# Create multiple non .txt files in a single directory without involving editors (vim, emacs, etc)

Tags: command-line

I know there must be a way to do it, only my skills are not that sharp.

Comment: I do care what their names are but not whether they are empty or not

Comment: This question could not get anymore homework-y if you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Create empty files

You can simply `touch` a find to create it and you can combine it with [bash range expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) to make this easier:

```
touch somefile  # Will create a single file called `somefile`
touch somefiles{01..10} # Will create 10 files called `somefile01` to `somefile10`
touch some{bar,baz} # Will create a file called `somebar` and one called `somebaz`
```

## Creating files with content

You can redirect output from a command into a file with bash redirection:

```
echo "some content" > somefile
ls > somefile
```

Or for longer fixed input you can use [heredocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
cat <<EOF >somefile
some multi
line
file
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the command-line `printf`, e.g.,

```
printf '\033[34mHello world\033[m' >hello
cat hello
```

and (you asked for multiple files):

```
for n in $(seq 1 7);do
    printf '\033[3%dmHello world\n\033[m' $n >hello
    eval mv hello hello.$n
done
cat hello.*
```

The script uses a counter, `$n` and creates a file, then uses `eval` to rename the output file, thereby creating several files (one for each color numbered 1-7).

I did this without using an editor.  You can too:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I'm not sure this is the answer; I think it is something much simpler than this. I just want to create  several files in a directory without using an editor (vi something.txt somethingelse.txt: so that it won't open all the files) If that makes sense.

Comment: @user2951181: You asked for a slice of bread, and Thomas gave you a club sandwich with a drink and a side of chips, but this is essentially equivalent to the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an empty file named `foo` you could:

```
>foo
```

to use empty redirection to a new file. That will create a 0-byte file, overwriting the existing file of that name if one exists. Though I personally prefer using `touch(1)` which will create a file if it doesn't exist or update the timestamps without overwriting the content if the file does exist, like:

```
touch foo
```

Comment: It you want to create a file that doesn't exist, without risking overwriting an existing file and without using `touch`, do `>>foo` instead of `>foo`.